# How do I merge two sets of routes under one path in React Router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have two sets of routes defined in different files. I want them both to be appended to the same path. There is no overlap in the route names. e.g.

```
const EditRoutes = () => <Routes>
  <Route path=":id/edit" element={<EditPage />} />
</Routes>

const PreviewRoutes = () => <Routes>
  <Route path=":id/preview" element={<PreviewPage />} />
</Routes>

const AppRoutes = () => <Routes>
  <Route path="/page/*">
    <PreviewRoutes />
    <EditRoutes />
  </Route>
</Routes> // Is invalid - how do I merge the two?
```

Following some hints from the errors, I have tried a few combinations, for example using React fragments rather than `<Routes>` in the child route sets but no luck.

How can I combine the routes under one path stem?

Comment: Why don't you break it down into sub routes? I.e. the child of the route, would be a routes component which further breaks into the sub routes? Or am I understanding your situation wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do apologize for not quite understanding your problem... So I'll just post one way of fixing the error you are having and give you the results of doing such. Please leave a comment if you were expecting something else. Thanks

```
const EditRoutes = () => <Routes>
  <Route path=":id/edit" element={<EditPage />} />
</Routes>

const PreviewRoutes = () => <Routes>
  <Route path=":id/preview" element={<PreviewPage />} />
</Routes>

const AppRoutes = () => <Routes>
  <Route path="/page/*" element={(<>
    <PreviewRoutes />
    <EditRoutes />
  </>)} />
</Routes>
```

Please be advised that the PreviewRoutes will correspond to /page/:id/preview
 And the EditRoutes will correspond to /page/:id/edit
By using a react fragment `<></>` to contain both as one element you can continue to use the element prop and avoid the error you are getting.
If this was what you wanted then I'm happy to help, if it was not what you were looking for, please explain further. Thanks

Comment: Ah, I had tried replacing `Routes` for the fragment both in the child files and the parent and using in the `element` prop as well as children of `Route` however I must have just not hit the right combination. Thanks @Sharp Dev!

Comment: Awesome, you are welcome, been there done that, seems like part of the job to overlook things.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the  component to nest the two routes together.

```
const AppRoutes = () => <Routes>
  <Route path="/page/*">
    <Routes>
      <Route path=":id/edit" element={<EditPage />} />
      <Route path=":id/preview" element={<PreviewPage />} />
    </Routes>
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but my main problem is that the routes are in different files